# Serving static files with dynamic URLs using nginx

Tags: python, django, nginx

I have some static files that I would like to serve, and I aware that Django and Python are not suitable for serving static files in a production environment.

My current set up is nginx with python/django behind it wither via nginx_fastcgi or uwsgi workers. Nginx serves up static files like the CSS and the Javascript, and all the dynamic pages are passed on to python to generate.

However there are urls like `/user/input/battleships.in`. Here `battleships.in` is a static file located on the filesystem at `$MEDIA_ROOT/users/$request.user.username. Is there a way to have django determine the correct url, and then proxy the request back to nginx to serve the static file?

Comment: check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1609273/how-to-make-a-private-download-area-with-django and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7296642/django-understanding-x-sendfile

Comment: Between those two links I was able to figure out what to do. Would you make an answer simply saying use X-Accel-Redirect so I can mark it as answered?

Comment: glad it helps. You could also post and pick up an final solution later if its helps in code, maybe some package named `django-downloadble` =p

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try to be not that trival =)

use X-accel module of Nginx. check

- http://wiki.nginx.org/X-accel
- [How to make a private download area with django?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1609273/how-to-make-a-private-download-area-with-django)
- [Django - Understanding X-Sendfile](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7296642/django-understanding-x-sendfile)